# Javascript prototype question

Tags: javascript, memory, prototype

while i was reading about prototype in javascript, I had a question.

Let's say I have the following functions and objects

```
Function #1:
function Rectangle(w,h){
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.area = function(){return this.width * this.height}
}

var object1 = new Rectangle(10,5);
var object11 = new Rectangle(5,5);


Function #2:
function Rectangle(w,h){
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function(){ return this.width * this.height; }

var object2 = new Rectangle(10,5);
var object22 = new Rectangle(5,5);
```

As far as I understand object2 and object22 use less memory than object1 and object11 because function #2 uses prototype.

is this correct?

Comment: Duplicate ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: @SergeS // You are right. Let's close it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is theoretically correct, because Function 1 creates a unique `function` for `area` each time it is called, whereas objects created with Function 2 all reference a common function.

However, each JavaScript engine will have different optimisations, and it is possible to optimise Function 1  so that internally each object points to the same function, *until one of them is modified* (this is necessary because as far as the language is concerned, each function is unique, and attaching a property to one should not affect the others).

There is very little documentation on the web about the specific optimisations performed by each browser, but here are a couple of references that seem to point towards some form of closure optimisation:

- https://groups.google.com/group/v8-users/browse_thread/thread/3a4eeecb8569a251?pli=1
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Functions

Answer (score 1):

It's "correct" for the classic view of Javascript. I think modern javascript compilers may alleviate the wastefulness of the first approach, but if you are creating lots of small objects that could share a function on the prototype, I still consider it good style to do so.